# Yahoo Home / Mail stuck in "waiting for yahoo.com" in firefox with ubuntu 13.04

Tags: firefox, email, yahoo

i am new to linux and chose ubuntu 13.04 as my first attempt on the OS.
So i kept a dual boot option with windows xp/ ubuntu 13.04.

Now the issue is that when i try to open yahoo.com or mail.yahoo.com it is stuck in loading, indefinitely, 
No errors or warnings it just says waiting for yahoo.com.
Other sites load just fine in same browser like google, gmail,

It loads fine in XP with firefox.

I have tried the install/ remove unity-webapps-yahoomail fix to no avail.

I have tried to connect via ip addess but doesnt connect so no DNS issues.

I can ping yahoo.com so no network issues though i use a dsl connection

I have cleared the cache , history and cookies without any effect.

I tried searching but could not find any solution or even why such a thing happens, it seems to plague only a "limited" number of people so if anyone has an answer or atleast why the problem exists please help, i would hate to have to keep XP just to open my mail.

Changed browser, no change still cant open the website, even tried IE 8 using wine to no avail.
Cant even add it to thunderbird.

Comment: Update: There are a few other sites which dont load eg: mangareader.net,
Also tried with different browsers still not working , should i just reinstall Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

Try viewing your yahoo email with Google Chrome to help narrow-down trouble-shooting and for immediate access. 

 http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-install-google-chrome-in-ubuntu-linux-12-xx-13-xx/

You could run some diagnostics like tcpdump to help identify the problem; it looks something like this from Terminal:

```
sudo tcpdump -i wlan0 host www.yahoo.com -w /tmp/plz_yahoo
sudo tcpdump -i wlan0 host www.yahoo.com -r /tmp/plz_yahoo
```

http://danielmiessler.com/study/tcpdump/#.Ukurunh3-Tx

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem opening yahoo mail on firefox. I used to use 2 browsers, chrome and firefox and use firefox primarily to open yahoo mail. Now I use chrome only since I have no problem opening yahoo mail in Chrome.